# Binding a json list to HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, json

I get a JSON array list of objects from database.

this is spitted to client side on page load of the current usercontrol

```
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonList = json.Serialize(mylList);             
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HomeCarouselScript", string.Concat("<script type='text/javascript'> var carouselData = ", jsonList, ";</script>"));
```

the json structure is like this 
json has collection of objects called Active. 
each active object has property called Name, Lastname, Address

i want to display all the objects in to HTML div in this structure 
for each object present can we add following template to the main container. for each existing object in the j son list i am trying to add it the main div container.

```
<div id="maincontainer">
   <div class="item">
         Object.Name
         <div class="subcategory">
            <h4>
              Object.Age
            </h4>
            <p>               
             Object.Address
            </p>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an HTML template engine like Mustache or Handlebars and turn your markup into something like this:

```
{{#each item}}  
      <div class="item">
        {{Name}}
          <div class="subcategory">
            <h4>
              {{Age}}
            </h4>
            <p>               
              {{Address}}
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: is it supported in IE8 and other browsers... we tried angular which is not supported in IE8 and now we have to re do again

Comment: According to docs, handlebars supports IE6+. Btw, angular 1.2 still supports IE8.

Comment: angular really  just 1.2 or 1.2.26 as well